# Please help me with RegExp. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "&lt;% some-text-here %&gt";

alert( str.match(/&lt;% (.*) %&gt/ig) ); // result in ["&lt;% main-menu-music %&gt"]
```

I need to get alert with "some-text-here". Help me plz. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the captured groups, you need `RegExp.exec`:

```
var match = /&lt;% (.*) %&gt/ig.exec("&lt;% some-text-here %&gt")
//match[1] == "some-text-here"
```

Comment: Well... that's it right there - `/&lt;% (.*) %&gt/ig` will _match_ "&lt;% " followed by any number of any characters followed by " %&gt", and it will _capture_ those characters "in between" - that is why you'll find what you're looking for in the 2nd element (index `1`) of the returned array. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Missing closing `)`

```
alert( str.match(/&lt;%(.*)%&gt/ig));
```

Answer (score 0):

Match returns an array, i would recommend to use replace

```
alert(str.replace(/[%\s]*&[glt;%\s]+/ig, ''));
```